# AsyncAPI - How to distribute definition over different files

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, asyncapi

I am  thinking of using AsyncAPI in my project for documenting the RabbitMQ messaging system.

What I need to do is, rather than creating a single yaml/json file for all the messages in the application, I want to create the AsyncAPI definition for each message in its own file, very much like its done in Swagger.

I am using Swagger 2.0, on a node express server for the REST API definitions. For the definition of the APIs, I write comments on each API with the `@swagger` decorator for Swagger to pick up the documentation. For example:

```
/**
* @swagger
* /user/register:
*   post:
*     description: Register a new user
...
...
*/
```

I also have a common definition in a `routes.js` file, where I define all the reusables.

Such definitions sit on the top of each API end point file. Swagger, collects all these documentations distributed over various files, and creates a single documentation for all the APIs in the application.

I was wondering if something similar can be done in AsyncAPI and if yes, how do I achieve that.

Would really appreciate your response on this.

Thanks,
Rachit

Answer (score 0):

> What I need to do is, rather than creating a single yaml/json file for all the messages in the application, I want to create the AsyncAPI definition for each message in its own file, very much like its done in Swagger.

Split definition of schema objects across several files is [possible in AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/specifications/2.0.0#referenceObject) exactly in the same way [like in OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)

> I am using Swagger 2.0, on a node express server for the REST API definitions. For the definition of the APIs, I write comments on each API with the @swagger decorator for Swagger to pick up the documentation. For example:

Up to now there is no [code-first tool](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/community/tooling#code-first-tools) to generate AsyncAPI from the JS source code